# JSON chaning value

Tags: java, json, tapestry

here goes the first JSON object to string output

```
{
  "session_id" : "zzz00001111",
  "name" : "Administrator",
}
```

but when I call,

```
response.remove("session_id");
response.append("session_id","abc12345678") ;
```

it becomes the following.

```
{
  "session_id" : [
    "abc12345678"
  ],
  "name" : "Administrator",
}
```

But i do not need to change the style of the JSON, i just need to chnage the value of the session_id. Any idea how to do it. I tired append it did not work.

Comment: Could you not just do `response.session_id = "abc12345678"`

Comment: its Java. I think its not working that way

Comment: What kind of object is your response?? JSONArray??

Comment: JSONObject (tapestry JSONObject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

response.put("session_id","session-id")

Answer (score 2):

The [`public JSONObject append(String key, Object value)`](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/json/JSONObject.html#append%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method's description says:

> Append values to the array under a key. If the key does not exist in
>   the JSONObject, then the key is put in the JSONObject with its value
>   being a JSONArray containing the value parameter. If the key was
>   already associated with a JSONArray, then the value parameter is
>   appended to it.

So, that's why you get an array.

The correct method to use is [`public JSONObject put(String key, Object value)`](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> Put a key/value pair in the JSONObject. If the value is null, then the
>   key will be removed from the JSONObject if it is present.

In your case, just use:

```
response.put("session_id","abc12345678");
```